# can anyone give a good definition of what a sub activity is?

Tags: android, android-activity

I've looked up definitions for sub activity but all i got was definitions for activity. Can anyone give a quick working definition of what a sub activity is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `startActivityForResult` from `Activity` A to start `Activity` B, then `Activity` B is usually referred to as a "sub-activity" of `Activity` A. That's all there is to it. It's not official Google terminology as far as I know.

See, for instance, [this tutorial by Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) or [this one by Oleg Mazurashu](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/11/using-subactivities-in-android/).

Answer (score 1):

In android as @Ted mentioned above activity started from another activity can be considered as sub activity. Also **[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)** are generally regarded as sub-activity having their own lifecycle closely tied to the hosting activity.